# Redirect to the same domain extension using WordPress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a domain name with three different Top-Level-Domain (TLD), using WordPress and hosted on OVH.

I'd like to redirect each of them to the `.com` one, using the HTTPS protocol and the `www` subdomain.

I usually use the following code sample to redirect my websites to https://www.example.com

```htaccess
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

**The problem:**

Since I'm using WordPress, there already is a redirection. Furthermore, I've node idea how to properly combine the TLD redirection to the https://www one.

Here is the .htaccess code from WordPress.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I would add the tag, "Apache" in your post, I'm sure you will get an answer pretty fast

Comment: Good idea, thanks.

Comment: A thing I always do is create a `no-wp.php` in the site root. When calling that file you can be certain WP is not messing with your redirects, as it's just a php file, and does nothing with WP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fastest solution <s>(though not the best one)</s> by modifying the htaccess

<s>Not the best one because WP can modify/overwrite the htaccess.</s> This is not true anymore, since WP uses [this function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/insert_with_markers/) to only rewrite its own part of the htaccess (between `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress`). Simply add your rules **before** WP's main rule. Here is an example combining all conditions in one rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off [OR,NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

  # BEGIN WordPress
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  # END WordPress

</IfModule>
```

### Plugin solution without touching the htaccess

You could use a plugin to do that properly. You can find plenty of them by searching on the web.

Comment: I tried this snippet and it creates an infinite redirection. Any idea why?

Comment: What is the original URL and which URL is infinitely redirected ? Maybe try using one at a time (but not both) between `SERVER_PORT` and `HTTPS` in conditions. It's possible either one or the other is not used properly by your server.

Comment: Note that it's also possible that the redirect comes from WP itself, depending on the configuration

Comment: Indeed, the redirection problem came from my Wordpress configuration (general settings menu). The WordPress Address was set to `https://example.com`, without including the `www` subdomain. Everything works fine with the code you provided. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress' rewrite rules are placed in between `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` block:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
...
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And WordPress [uses](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-admin/includes/misc.php#L219) its [`insert_with_markers()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/insert_with_markers/) function to make sure WordPress is only altering its own rewrite rules.

So WordPress wouldn't alter any rewrite rules *outside* of that block, and therefore you could safely add yours in the `.htaccess` file.

Now to redirect from a domain to another domain, the following worked well for me:

```
# BEGIN Redirect to another domain name
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?(example.net|example.info|example.xyz) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>

# END Redirect to another domain name

# Other rules here, if any.

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
...
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```